# MPMovie player exit fullscreen programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In MPMoviePlayer when movie player enters in a full screen & when i pressed done button it will exit full screen is there any other method by which i can exit the fullscreen  mode programmatically of mpmoview player.?

Comment: Do you want to exit the full screen mode or the whole screen on which movie is being played.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking into the [MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) I came across an instance method called:

`- (void)setFullscreen:(BOOL)fullscreen animated:(BOOL)animated`

And the definition of the method states clearly `Causes the movie player to enter or exit full-screen mode`.You might want to consider using this method when exiting the fullscreen mode by setting the boolean value of the fullscreen parameter to `NO`.

Hope this helps!